# Provider NAT traversal using OpenVPN server

Tags: linux, vpn, nat

I have a configured OpenVPN server with access to global internet and a connection with a server that is under NAT.

I need to achieve that, for example, when requesting a tcp port 2000 of a server with OpenVPN, so that it redirects the request to the connected server under NAT and returns a response from it.

Client <-Send request on 2000 port-> OpenVPN Linux Server <-Port: 1194-> Server

Is it possible to do this at the OpenVPN server level?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that on the VPN server. You need to set up a proxy appropriate for the service you want to proxy.